# Cannot fetch the previous query for matching

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
 $user_answer = $_POST['answ'];
$random = rand(1, 20);
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{if ($user_answer == $_SESSION['answer']) {
        echo '<br>RIGHT ANSWER<br>';
    } else {
        echo '<br>WRONG, THE RIGHT ANSWER IS ' . $_SESSION['answer'] . '<br>';
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT Questions,Answers FROM history WHERE questions_id=$random";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print_r($result);

echo 'QUESTION: ' . $result['Questions'];
$_SESSION['answer']=$result['Answers'];

?>
```

Hello. I am new to this php pdo thing. I wanted to make a query that fetches question and checks the answer input by users. But I cannot do this with various codes also. It always fetches the next questions and answer. SO gives wrong answer output.And is there any methods to continue the session cause its redirecting to my homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the question:
Please try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
   if (trim($user_answer) == trim($_SESSION['answer'])) {
        echo '<br>RIGHT ANSWER<br>';
    } else {
        echo '<br>WRONG, THE RIGHT ANSWER IS ' . $_SESSION['answer'] . '<br>';
    }
    unset($_SESSION['answer']);
}
```

I have unset the session variable.Please try this.

Comment: Yes but there are a set of questions and I tried regular id and also tried to use some array but cannot solve the problem.¨

Comment: It is better after I remove the unset($_SESSION['answer']); but still,this session still doesn't matches the right answer even if both input and the answer from data are same.

Comment: print both the answer it will help to debug